# How to change the default redirect behaviour of AccountController in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, simplemembership

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I use the `SimpleMembershipProvider` and the default `AccountController` but want to modify the behavior a little bit.

Right now my application has two logical parts - User part and Admin Panel. I also have two roles - User and Admin and all my logic for the admin panel is in `AdminController`.

The admin panel can be reached only by providing the correct URL, for example - `localhost:51200/admin` and as result I show a `Login` page.

So the problem is this - I don't have a standard login page like the one created by the default template. For now I have modified the `AccountController` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string controllerName = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return RedirectToAction("ManageContent", "Admin");
            }
            //string controllerName = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I want to be able to determine where the user will be redirected if the authentication/authorization fails based on from where the use have tried to log in. In my `AdminController` I have `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` so no matter if a standard user goes to `localhost:5555/admin` and provides OK credentials but don't have the necessary level or just incorrect log in information, if the log in attempt is made from the `localhost:6477/admin` I want to be able to redirect the user to a specific controller/action (most probably the again `localhost:54555/admin`) and if the user tries to log in from somewhere else, no matter where, I want to set another redirect location.

I have this :

```
string controllerName = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

just to check if I'm able to get the controller, it seems it's possible, so this could be some partial solution but yet I don't have an answer to what to do if the redirect comes from `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`.

Comment: You should look into areas. This allows you to have 2 controllers/views with the same name and are meant to provide a separation based on role.

Comment: I've thought about this (not too much tough) but if we talk only for this particular problem isn't it the same if I just write a login logic for both - `AdminController` which will be used only when you try to log for the admin panel and another in the `AccountController` for the rest of the application. What I think I will accomplish here is keeping it DRY by not having the same code in two places.